# Laravel, query where created_at format

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

In PostgreSQL and Laravel 5.1

I have this output query from Query Builder (raw):

```
select  *
from mytable
// some joins and stuff
where to_char(mytable.created_at, 'DD-MM-YYYY') = '20-06-2019'
```

I'm getting 0 values because that last line `where to_char(mytable.created_at, 'DD-MM-YYYY') = '2019-06-20'` is wrong.

`created_at` has this format: '2019-06-20 21:00:12'

How can I query with that time '20-06-2019' in my table?

Comment: Laravel tag is ok, that means that some Laravel helpers, Carbon, etc, could be used in the answer. That SQL is the raw ouput of a query builder.

Comment: If you want a Laravel solution, post a Laravel PHP query builder code, if you post a raw sql statement as question, you'll get a raw sql statement as an answer

Comment: its a `selectRaw`with all the sql inside

Comment: Yeah but how is Laravel related? Would you tag Laravel for an nginx config problem just because your site is served by nginx?

Comment: Because almost every Laravel devs usually have experienced problems with casting betwen those `created_at` format date, timestamp, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your char date into DATE and truncate date which you are getting from table can use below query

```
 select  *
 from mytable
 // some joins and stuff
 where trunc(mytable.created_at) = to_date('20-06-2019','dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Comment: SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function trunc(timestamp without time zone) does not exist

Comment: try to use `date_trunc` instead of `trunc`

Comment: SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function date_trunc(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Which database you are using ? is it SQL server or Oracle or something else?

Comment: OP's using postgres

Comment: can try with only `where DATE(mytable.created_at) = to_date('20-06-2019','dd-mm-yyyy'))` or can use like this `select '2010-01-01 12:00:00'::timestamp::date;` this will give you date in date variable and use that date while comparing to other date